# Scroll event is not fired inside directive - angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, scroll, dom-events

I'm stucked with problem. I have a directive for infinite-scroll where I listen for `scroll` event. The problem is that scroll event is only fired when I'm binding to `$window`:

```
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
  console.log('Gogo!'); //works!
});

element.bind('scroll', function () {
  console.log('Gogo!'); //doesn't work... :(((
});
```

Directive is inside `ng-view` I found this question, looks very similar to my problem - [Binding to events in a directive which is inside a ng-view doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088283/binding-to-events-in-a-directive-which-is-inside-a-ng-view-doesnt-work)

Anybody knows how to solve this?

**My directive:**

```
directives.directive('scrolly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var raw = element[0];

            element.bind('scroll', function () {
                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight > raw.scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.scrolly);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**My view:**

```
<ul class="items-wrap" scrolly="showMore()">
   <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please paste your view, and directive code.

Comment: @MattWay added code snippets

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4831/

The interesting thing is that I used your exact code, and everything seems to trigger fine (see all the littered `console.log()` calls). I suspect your problem has to do with your CSS styling though, as without the right use of overflow, I could not get the scroll event to trigger.

Comment: yeah, when I'm adding ``overflow: scroll`` to the ``ul`` it fires event.. but it's not nice regarding the ui..

Comment: hi @Matt Way when i use this code this give me error on `scope.$apply(attrs.scrolly)` undefined . y it is so can u help me ?

Answer (score 28):

It's likely because the element you're binding to doesn't "scroll".

The node that you're actually scrolling (the document, or maybe a div with a scroll overflow) is the thing that actually fires the event.

Try injecting `$document` into your directive and setting up the scroll event on that:

`$document.bind('scroll', function (){});`

Also, ditch the if statement on the inside of handler until you're sure you have the event firing properly, *then* add it back.

Just to start:

```
app.directive('scrolly', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            $document.bind('scroll', function () {
                scope.$apply(attrs.scrolly);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then work in your examination of the element positioning and other logic.

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1 It's likely because the element you're binding to doesn't "scroll" - is the exact reason why scroll event didn't fire. In my case table is inside div and div can scroll but not table.

Comment: @Ben Lesh, +1 because I had the same problem: "scrolly" wasn't fired because of  "overflow-x: none;" on my <div> !  (tested on Chrome 54 and I.E. 11). The solution is to set the style "overflow: scroll; "

Comment: I think it is a bug from Angular, because it works fine when using pure JS like  "document.getElementById("myDIV").onscroll = function() {....}" with the style "overflow-x: none;"