# angular 2 set style when window scrolls to element

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

In angular 2 can I do something like

```
<div (onEnter)="doSomething()">
</div>
```

which would trigger when the windows is near an element within a large component.

I am trying to avoid having to write a bunch of components with custom entrance animation.  so I wanted to set the style to reference animate.css in the dosomething() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only the syntax dictates `(enter)` rather than `(onEnter)`.

Plus, you're using angular2, hence the proper usage is of LESS or SCSS files. 
For pre-processing style files read here http://lesscss.org/

Comment: I used 
<div class="feature-block" (enter)="test()">
within my component and the test() function is never called as I scroll through the page.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but (enter) and (onEnter) refer to mouse enter, not windows scrolling. 
There's a (scroll)/(onscroll event) but I think you might find this solution more suitable :[link]http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4831/
Use the 'raw' object to determone offsetHeight and thus location of object on window.

The fiddle was a solution to an issue presented here
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989923/scroll-event-is-not-fired-inside-directive-angular-js

Plus, if you can post more or even all of your code it would be more beneficial.